# Creating a C++ console program on MacOS that can be opened on Windows?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, visual-studio

I have Xcode on my macOS partition and Visual Studio 2017 Professional on my Windows partition if that helps. I want to make a C++ project within macOS (preferably in Xcode) but also be able to copy the project and open it on Windows and be able to build it within Windows so it can be run on Windows. Without having to remake the entire project again.

Any ways I can make a C++ project on macOS and open it on Windows basically. I can't find any solutions online.

Comment: Maybe a cleaner solution is to create a repository for your project and then just ignore config files from your IDEs but I am not sure I get your question.

Comment: Is the problem one of accessing files or one of C++ build tools? If the latter use CMake.

Comment: Perhaps [Visual Studio for Mac](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/)  :-)